# What is the X server?

Tags: xorg, xserver

I have been using Ubuntu for quite some time but, I have no idea what the X server is?
I hear it quite often.

I would like to know what the X Server is and what it does. How `~/.xinitrc` file is used and knowing what the x.org does in the realm of X Server?

Comment: Not really an ubuntu question.

Comment: May be. But i am on Ubuntu, and if there was something specific to X regarding Ubuntu, I would like to know that.

Comment: Hm, I'd say personally that this is a fair question, IMO. A new ubuntu user, I think this is relevant information, and it's not really something he'd know where more properly to look for otherwise since he doesnt know what it is.

Comment: @enzotib  seeing how ubuntu is linux... this is a ubuntu question. see http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/47/how-do-we-tell-if-a-question-belongs-here-or-rather-at-stackoverflow-superuser/52#52

Answer (score 58, accepted):

X is an application that manages one or more graphics displays and one or more input devices (keyboard, mouse, etc.) connected to the computer.

It works as a server and can run on the local computer or on another computer on the network. Services can communicate with the X server to display graphical interfaces and receive input from the user.

It's worth noting, a common component used with an X server is the Window Manager, an application that manages the resizing and moving of windows and decorative elements of windows such as title bars, minimize, and close buttons.

The X server can be started with the 'startx' command, or more commonly, from a display manager such as gdm.

`~/.xinitrc` is a shell script used by xinit, that starts the X server when not using a display manager, to define some application to start automatically in the X server.

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is a configuration file used to give the X server information about the hardware components used, but now the X server can avoid using it, because it is capable of autoconfiguring itself.

Comment: i am on Ubuntu maverick, it must be using gdm right? so ~/.xinitrc will help or something else?

Comment: you can avoid using it, for startup applications just use the System->Preference->Startup-applications menu item

Comment: I am new to this concept. Does it mean x server is X.org, or X.org is a concrete implementation of x server?

Comment: @QinshengZhang X.org is a concrete implementation of a X server

Answer (score 8):

As the above poster mentioned, `X` is a server (meaning a program which other programs call upon and be called by) which is responsible for creating a graphical environment and if it fails for whatever reason, you'll be greeted by Command Line Interface (CLI).

The term `server` can also be said to apply to PulseAudio, which is the sound server, and it calls applications and is called upon to produce sound.