# Can I act on the event that a window opens without polling?

Tags: bash, window, c++, c, events

I am trying to find a way to detect the event of a window (any window) being opened in Ubuntu 16.04

I would like to be able to detect the "window open" event and check if the opened window was my sought window and thereafter run a bash script or a C/C++ function.

So far I've found that I can use `wmctrl -l` to find which windows are already opened. I could use this command and perhaps `grep` to find if my sought window is opened and then act on this information.

I'd prefer not to poll, as I'd not want the application to stand idle when the window opens. The action should be as "instantaneous" as possible.

Is there an event or signal I could listen for to achieve this? From the kernel, window manager (Compiz) or maybe some log file that changes?

**EDIT:** 
To clarify, I have an application (not under my control) which might show a window at any time, this window does not have a title but it does have the WM_CLASS set (the WM_CLASS is the same for all windows of the application). I want to act upon the event that this window is shown (or created, whichever is best/easier).

It doesn't seem like the window is opened "within" the main applications window. Using `xwininfo -children -id <window-id>` shows that the main application and the sought window are on different branches, connected to "the root window".

The branches looks like this, where R is "the root node"; A is a root node of the main application's branch and Y is the root of the branch with sought window W:

```
    R
   / \
  A   Y
 /\    \
B  C    X
    \    \
     Q    W
```

So I'm hoping that I can find the unique structure of Y-X-W

I'm not sure I have to listen to all windows, but it is my assumption that I'll have to check what happens within "the root window" and try to find the sought window.

Comment: Just found that `xprop` has a `-spy` option: *Examine window properties forever, looking for property change events.* I have no idea whether that is helpful, but it's the only thing I found that doesn't involve polling.

Comment: I have looked at `xprop -spy` before, I discarded it since I was thinking that I needed to listen to the window I was searching for. But you might be on to something. Tested it out by `xprop -spy -root` and it doesn't show any info at window creation, but it does make a note when there is a focus change and, as it happens, the window I'm searching for will be pushed to the front. So maybe I can use it, I'll give it a shot and see if I can solve it :)

Comment: Are there any news, did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, I manged to create a solution using the spy option. I also had some luck with the xlib library. I'll write something up for an answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found two ways of solving this problem.

1. Use the `xprop -spy -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` command in combination with `grep` in a bash script.
2. Create a C++ (could have been C or python as well my project was in C++ to begin with) application using the Xlib library to listen for events from the [X-server](https://askubuntu.com/a/7885/701969).

I ended up using alternative 1 but I'll provide some info on both below.

**Using xprop:**
The application which creates the sought window always puts the new window on top and in focus. The `xprop -spy <window-id>`command allows one to listen to changes in the properties of `<window-id>` and `-root` is the id of the "root window" (R in the tree in the question above). To listen for changes of specific properties we can provide the property's name in this case `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` which holds the id of the window currently in focus, [see spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s03.html). We then get a stream of output like this:

```
_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x3c00010
```

and can use `grep` to extract the ID. To check if the active window is the sought window we need to know what makes it unique, this might be different for everyone but most likely the first filter would be the `WM_CLASS` property, [see description](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-4.html#WM_CLASS). Here is a small example of this:

```
#!/bin/bash
class_name=$1

# regex for extracting hex id's
grep_id='0[xX][a-zA-Z0-9]\{7\}'

xprop -spy -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | grep --line-buffered -o $grep_id |
while read -r id; do
    class="`xprop -id $id WM_CLASS | grep $class_name`"
    if [ -n "$class" ]; then
        # Found a window with the correct WM_CLASS now what makes your
        # window unique?
    fi
done
```

**Bash gist:**
[Here](https://gist.github.com/christian-eriksson/286d0d8cc96dce7895847c1a9b27701a) is a gist for the case in the question, where the tree was the identifying factor.

*Limitations of `xprop -spy`*: this doesn't specifically listen to a window opening, rather when a window is focused. This means that if the window stays open, goes out of focus and then comes into focus again, this script will still report this event.

**Xlib programming:**
This is more complicated but also more powerful. Some great resources for getting started are:

- [A Xlib Manual](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/) and [short tutorial](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib-tutorial/) by Christophe Tronche
- Alan's [tutorial on Xlib](http://xopendisplay.hilltopia.ca/2009/Jan/Xlib-tutorial-part-1----Beginnings.html).

For this one has to open a connection and register as a listener to the X-server:

```
// Open connection to X server
Display *dsp = XOpenDisplay(NIL);
assert(dsp);

// Start listening to root window
XSelectInput(dsp, DefaultRootWindow(dsp), SubstructureNotifyMask);
```

Depending on which events one is looking for a [EventMask](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/processing-overview.html) should be chosen.

For a continuous application (which want to handle subsequent events) one probably want to set an error handler function which should return 0 (maybe with a warning) so execution continues smoothly, like so:

```
XSetErrorHandler(bad_window_handler);
```

In a loop one can then handle events from the X-server

```
XEvent e;
XNextEvent(dsp, &e); // blocks until next event from X-server
```

To handle the event in `e` we can check the type of `e`

```
e.type == CreateNotify    // A window was created
e.type == ReparentNotify  // A window got a new parent
e.type == MapNotify       // A window was drawn
e.type == DestroyNotify   // A window was destroyed
```

The `XEvent` [struct](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/structures.html) contains information in different types of struct depending on the event type.

The following libraries are needed:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
```

And applications should be compiled with the `-lX11` flag to include the Xlib libraries.

**Xlib gists + Gotchas:**
I've created two gists that listens to events from X-server. Note that I was interested in the structure of a window's tree for identification. Others might have other properties to uniquely identify windows.

*[The first](https://gist.github.com/christian-eriksson/32795a7185cbc5f968c4fa59b77d1ed0)* listens to the `CreateNotify` event to determine if a window with the correct WM_CLASS was created, call it W. At this point the window will likely not be in the correct tree structure. For example it might be created as a child to the root rather than windows controlled by the application. We therefore listen to the `ReparentNotify` event to see if W has a new parent.

Unfortunately we are not guaranteed the correct tree structure here either, as other windows might later be added to W's tree. But if W's tree structure is unique and it's shape is not a sub-tree of another window with the same class we can at least find these window's by checking `ReparentNotify` (we might not even need to check the `CreateNotify` as we can check WM_CLASS at any point we have a window-id).

*[The Second](https://gist.github.com/christian-eriksson/899c8a8d4a7800cd980972efbeba817d)* listens to the `MapNotify` event and checks the structure of the window's tree. It then looks for the correct WM_CLASS in the tree. After this one could go on to determine if the structure is correct.

Again, at the `MapNotify` we are not guaranteed a "finished" tree structure. However it seems that the structure generally "settles" a short time after this event. To be reasonably sure that the structure won't change I added a short pause before collecting the tree. How long this pause should be in order to not risk other changes to the tree I don't know, 500ms seemed to work well for me.

**Misc:**
X11 windows can be created in [many different languages](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Window_creation/X11#Xlib), so I imagine listening to them would be possible in many different languages as well.

Some tools to investigate windows with:

- `xprop`
- `xwininfo` specifically with options `-tree` or `-children`

One can also check the source code of the commands above, [xprop](https://sourcecodebrowser.com/xprop/1.0.1/xprop_8c_source.html) and [xwininfo](https://sourcecodebrowser.com/xwininfo/1.0.1/xwininfo_8c_source.html), for some guidance and inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

to excute a command on the event that a window opens without polling using a while loop, one could use xdotool :-

```
<code_that_triggers_window_opening> & xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --name 'window_name' && <command_to_excute_on_window_open_event>
```

I have no clue whether xdotool implements this feature internally by polling or not.

All Credit for the idea goes to this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1187586