# Trying to open a new ubuntu terminal window from the existing window

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have a new virtual environment in Ubuntu (terminal only) and I am trying to open a new terminal window (so I would have two views) however when I enter gnome-terminal to open a new terminal window I get the a command not found error.

[image]

Could someone let me know what I need to do to open more than one terminal window please?

Tried adding tasksel and got back:
[image]

I also tried:
sudo apt update; sudo apt install tasksel
[image]

Thanks

Comment: `gnome-terminal` is the terminal if you have GNOME desktop loaded/running.  You mention *Ubuntu (terminal only)*  which implies to me you don't have GUI/GNOME there, so why would gnome-terminal be there?  I'm not quite sure what you're after; (1) ctrl+alt+f4 to switch to term 4? or (2) `bash` to open a new shell? .. or (3) are expecting/wanting gui features to work despite not running a gui?

Comment: Thanks @guiverc - I would just like to be able to view my Ubantu environment from more than one terminal view (so I have 2 or more terminal screens for me to view different parts of the environment I'm working on).  I've tried Ctrl-Alt -T without success as well

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+T is a another gui/X shortcut so shouldn't work if you are using server with text terminal only (no X or gui operational).   Ctrl+alt+Fn key will jump to another text terminal (you can have more or less than the default, but only one displays at a time), but to have more than one display on a screen requires X (or wayland, etc) to be enabled & running (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/7881/what-is-the-x-server or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System)

Comment: Virtual consoles anyone? We still have those, right?

Answer (score 6):

Because your setup is "terminal only", you currently cannot run apps that run a graphical user interface or GUI. However, you can use something like `tmux` which will allow you to "tile" your terminal.

Run the following commands to install `tmux`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tmux
```

Then, to run `tmux`, just type the following command:

```
tmux
```

Now, to run in "split window" mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd> at the same time, release both, and then press the <kbd>%</kbd> key.

The the <kbd>%</kbd> key is actually <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> of course.

To navigate to the left and right terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd> at the same time, release both, and then press the left or the right arrow key.

[Click here to view "a quick and easy guide to tmux".](https://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-tmux/)

[Click here to view "a tmux crash course".](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/a-tmux-crash-course)

---

**Alternatively**, if you want to install a complete desktop setup with application-windows and graphical applications, you can run the following command:

```
sudo tasksel
```

Then, you can select your desired desktop environment. Choosing the "Ubuntu desktop" will install Gnome applications such as Gnome Shell and `gnome-terminal`. Do not select any of the "live cd" options.

You can use your arrow keys to scroll down to "Ubuntu desktop" or you can choose any one of the other [Ubuntu flavours](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) (like Xubuntu desktop, Ubuntu Mate desktop, etc . . .). Each of these desktop environments uses a different set of applications. For example, Xubuntu uses `xfce4-terminal` instead of `gnome-terminal`.

Finally, use the <kbd>space bar</kbd> to select or deselect a desktop and then use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to select "OK" and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to install.

---

**NOTE:** [because of a bug in tasksel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/1779645), DO NOT use tasksel to uninstall packages. ONLY use tasksel to install.

Comment: If the system complains that `tasksel` is not installed, you can install by running the following command: `sudo apt update; sudo apt install tasksel`

Comment: Thanks @mchid I tried sudo taskel and sudo apt update; sudo apt install tasksel without success (please see edit to the question for output from running the commands.  Any idea what I should try?  Thx

Comment: @Stacey If you are sure that your virtualbox is set up properly to be connected to the internet, you can do a temporary DNS fix by running the following command: `echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf` Then, try to update and install again. However, you will need to set this again after you reboot.

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned by other, apparently you have a server (no GUI) installation, and therefor only one "console" available.

What you can do though, is using `ssh` to connect to your Ubuntu virtual server:

```
ssh user@ip-address-of-server
```

or use the `putty` application to do the same. Putty also works from Windows. This will give you as many terminal sessions as you like.

Comment: Within nowadays Windows 10 you can use `ssh` directly from `cmd.exe` (and power-shell), also WSL is available.